# Configuring output of % static in django

Tags: python, django

[image]

I'm experimenting with django-distill (https://github.com/mgrp/django-distill) to generate a static site from a django project. i'm using django 1.10.8 . My main template contains:

```
<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
{% load staticfiles %}
<link href="{% static "css/bootstrap.min.css" %}" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- Custom CSS -->
<link href="{% static "css/landing-page.css" %}" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.5.0/slick.css"/>
```

The paths to the css and js files are correct when I run the project locally on my windows system. However when I look at the source html I see:

[image]

on my windows system this works with a running sever, i.e.

```
 http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

but it breaks with static files and I have to change these to

```
<link href="./static/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Is there any way to set % static to render to

```
./static/ instead of /static/
```

Comment: You can change `STATIC_URL` settings. But why would you use a relative url for static assets? Relative urls are really never necessary, and usually just cause problems.

Comment: I don't understand your explanation of "but it breaks with static files and I have to change these to". Both urls are the same, aren't they? What do you need to change?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATIC_URL